# Can applications access users information without having permissions?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, security, permissions

[image: AM pre-release result]

When i scan apps with
Am pre_release Some apps have this access, which is in the photo. My question is, what is this access?  Can you explain about it first?  And in the second place While camera permission is closed for the app ( in setting )
It can use the camera without user's knowledge or not? And if  app can not use it directly, is it possible to do this through intent?

Comment: your picture is pretty much self-explaining. once revoked, the app will ask again until granted. in your example the pkgname is 'android' (no app)